# How to formulate an economics differential calculus problem?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a toy problem that I cannot seem to formulate (let alone solve). I was hoping someone could provide me insights on how to formulate the problem and how to solve it.

The problem is as follows: assume that we have a simpel gasoline generator, which can generate a maximum capacity of 250 KW. If we were to run the gasoline generator at full capacity (250 KW), we would have an efficiency of 1KWh of gasoline being converted into 0.5KWh of energy. This will cost us, with labour and such 55 USD/KWh.

Of course we cannot turn the gasoline generator on and off all the time, so we decide to always let it run at half capacity (125KW). This is less efficient than full capacity, therefore 1KWh of gasoline only can get 0.3KWh of energy. Running at half capacity with labour and such would cost us 30 USD/KWh.

The idea is to formulate the differential equation and get the supply curve. However, I am very interested in the formulation part as I am stuck at that part.

We know that the marginal cost at the maximum capacity is:

$$\frac{\delta C}{\delta Q} = 55$$ at $Q = 250$, since we are delivering that quantity.

At half capacity we have:

$$\frac{\delta C}{\delta Q} = 30$$, at $Q = 125$.

1. I suspect that my marginal cost should actually be a function of my quantity variable, but I am not quite sure what the simplest way to model it is. I am thinking of $MC(Q) = 0.2Q + 5$. Is this correct / the right direction?

$$\frac{\delta C}{\delta Q} = 0.2Q + 5$$

2. How can I incorporate the "loss of efficiency", i.e. the 0.2KWh reduction of efficiency in my production? I can't seem to write that down anywhere.

Thanks for helping out and increasing my understanding.

Note: in addition if additional assumptions are needed, such as linearity or anything else, please let me know.

Comment: Make sure you are being clear about total cost, average cost, and marginal cost. What are you assuming about fixed and variable costs? Similarly for efficiency.I recommend writing efficiency as a function of capacity, and then thinking about the cost structure.